# Negative one (-1) passing validation in jQuery Validate plugin. Fix?

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate, validation

I have a drop down box with the first option value as "-1", which I want to fail on validation but is passing.

```
<option value="-1">Select Option</option>
<option value="optionOne">Select Option</option>
<option value="optionTwo">Select Option</option>
```

How can make this fail in the jQuery Validation Plugin (http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation)?

Comment: How do you do the validation?

Comment: I'm assuming somewhere in the jQuery plugin it checks if the value is empty like this: if(value == ""){//not valid}else{//valid}. And I would like it to check something along the lines of: if(value == "" || value == "-1"{//not valid}else{//valid}. Anyone know where I can do this in the plugin? Its a bit big for me to understand.

Comment: Need to see your Validation config. Also, have you used your browser's JS debugger to step through? Also, there's a Validate option called `debug` that might help you as well.

Answer (score 2):

Is this the validation plugin you are using: [bassistance.de](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)?

If so, then you can force a `required` error with this:

```
<select id="myselect" class="required error">
<option value>Select Option</option>
<option value="optionOne">Select Option</option>
<option value="optionTwo">Select Option</option>
</select>
```

This work as long as you don't need the `Select Option` value to be explicitly set to `-1`.

**UPDATE**

Since you need the value to be `-1`, then you can write your own custom validator:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("validator-class", function(value, element){
        // validate
    return validity;
}, "Error Message");
```

So in your case, using the validation you provided:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("choose-option", function(value, element){
        return ! (value == "" || value == "-1");
}, "Please select an option");
```

Comment: Yep, that's the plugin. But the value needs to be set to "-1".

Comment: Nice! Where do I place this function within the plugin?

Comment: If you still have the `additional-methods.js` file that comes with the plugin, then you can put it there or you can put it your own file. Just be sure to include it after the validation plugin.

Comment: Arg. For some reason I can't get this to work. Maybe I'm missing something obvious?

Comment: Did you add the validation class to the `<select>`?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a [custom method](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod#namemethodmessage), like this:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("your_select", function(value, element) { 
  return value != -1; 
}, "Please select something");
```

See it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cambraca/T6g8J/).